# Wrong PID for busybox init process

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, busybox

I have set up a small embedded linux that uses busybox. I am facing a problem of which I'm not sure if its caused by busybox or the kernel.

The problem is, that the `init` process does not have process ID 1. Heres the output of `ps`:

```
1 root       0:26 [swapper/0]
2 root       0:00 [kthreadd]
3 root       0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
4 root       0:00 [kworker/0:0]
5 root       0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
6 root       0:00 [kworker/u4:0]
7 root       0:00 [rcu_preempt]
8 root       0:00 [rcu_sched]
...
549 root       0:00 {linuxrc} init
...
```

I guess the other processes before `init` are all kernel processes. The reason why this is a problem is that orphaned processes are given the parent process ID 1, which should be the `init` process, but now this `swapper` process is receiving them all.

I noticed that something is going wrong when I observed a lot of zombie processes.

So somehow either `init` must be forced to PID 1, or orphaned processes must be assigned to the correct `init` PID.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

---

**Update: Some more information on my setup**

The target is an ARM board with a Xilinx Zynq chip. I was using the Xilinx linux Kernel, and compiled busybox myself (v1.20.2).

The command line is:

`ramdisk_size=65536 console=ttyPS0,115200 earlyprintk`

Here are the bootlogs up to the moment that the init script is started:

```
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.13.0-xilinx (cone@cone-ubuntu) (gcc version 4.8.1 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.11-53) ) #5 SMP PREEMPT Sun J4
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc090] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=18c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Xilinx Zynq
[    0.000000] bootconsole [earlycon0] enabled
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 8 pages/cpu @c101e000 s10176 r8192 d14400 u32768
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 130048
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: ramdisk_size=65536 console=ttyPS0,115200 earlyprintk
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 501272K/524288K available (4781K kernel code, 307K rwdata, 1692K rodata, 197K init, 5345K bss, 23016K reserved, 0K hi)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xe0800000 - 0xff000000   ( 488 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xe0000000   ( 512 MB)
[    0.000000]     pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc065a600   (6474 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc065b000 - 0xc068c7c0   ( 198 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc068e000 - 0xc06dac78   ( 308 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc06dac84 - 0xc0c13230   (5346 kB)
[    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU lockdep checking is enabled.
[    0.000000]  Dump stacks of tasks blocking RCU-preempt GP.
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] ps7-slcr mapped to e0802000
[    0.000000] zynq_clock_init: clkc starts at e0802100
[    0.000000] Zynq clock init
[    0.000000] sched_clock: 32 bits at 325MHz, resolution 3ns, wraps every 13215283196ns
[    0.000000] ps7-ttc #0 at e0804000, irq=43
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000000] Lock dependency validator: Copyright (c) 2006 Red Hat, Inc., Ingo Molnar
[    0.000000] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_SUBCLASSES:  8
[    0.000000] ... MAX_LOCK_DEPTH:          48
[    0.000000] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_KEYS:        8191
[    0.000000] ... CLASSHASH_SIZE:          4096
[    0.000000] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_ENTRIES:     16384
[    0.000000] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_CHAINS:      32768
[    0.000000] ... CHAINHASH_SIZE:          16384
[    0.000000]  memory used by lock dependency info: 3695 kB
[    0.000000]  per task-struct memory footprint: 1152 bytes
[   13.207599] Calibrating delay loop... 1292.69 BogoMIPS (lpj=6463488)
[   13.207606] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[   13.207607] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
[   13.207609] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[   13.207610] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[   13.207611] Setting up static identity map for 0x489b98 - 0x489bf0
[   13.207612] L310 cache controller enabled
[   13.207613] l2x0: 8 ways, CACHE_ID 0x410000c8, AUX_CTRL 0x72760000, Cache size: 512 kB
[   13.207627] CPU1: Booted secondary processor
[   13.207641] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[   13.207642] Brought up 2 CPUs
[   13.207644] SMP: Total of 2 processors activated.
[   13.207644] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[   13.207646] devtmpfs: initialized
[   13.207647] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant 9 rev 4
[   13.207650] regulator-dummy: no parameters
[   13.207651] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[   13.207651] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[   13.207654] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[   13.207654] cpuidle: using governor menu
[   13.207658] syscon f8000000.ps7-slcr: regmap [mem 0xf8000000-0xf8000fff] registered
[   13.207660] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
[   13.207662] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
[   13.207663] zynq-ocm f800c000.ps7-ocmc: ZYNQ OCM pool: 256 KiB @ 0xe0880000
[   13.207672] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[   13.207674] vgaarb: loaded
[   13.207674] SCSI subsystem initialized
[   13.207675] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[   13.207676] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[   13.207677] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[   13.207678] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   13.207679] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   13.207680] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[   13.207681] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[   13.207682] PTP clock support registered
[   13.207683] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[   13.207685] DMA-API: preallocated 4096 debug entries
[   13.207686] DMA-API: debugging enabled by kernel config
[   13.207687] Switched to clocksource arm_global_timer
[   13.207696] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[   13.207697] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[   13.207698] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 147456 bytes)
[   13.207699] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[   13.207700] TCP: reno registered
[   13.207701] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 20480 bytes)
[   13.207702] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 20480 bytes)
[   13.207703] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[   13.207704] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[   13.207705] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[   13.207706] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[   13.207707] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[   13.207708] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[   13.207709] rootfs image is not initramfs (no cpio magic); looks like an initrd
[   13.207717] Freeing initrd memory: 6004K (df551000 - dfb2e000)
[   13.207718] hw perfevents: enabled with ARMv7 Cortex-A9 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[   13.207722] jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) (SUMMARY)  © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
[   13.207723] msgmni has been set to 990
[   13.207724] io scheduler noop registered
[   13.207724] io scheduler deadline registered
[   13.207725] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[   13.207728] dma-pl330 f8003000.ps7-dma: unable to set the seg size
[   13.207729] dma-pl330 f8003000.ps7-dma: Loaded driver for PL330 DMAC-2364208
[   13.207731] dma-pl330 f8003000.ps7-dma:      DBUFF-128x8bytes Num_Chans-8 Num_Peri-4 Num_Events-16
[   13.207733] e0001000.serial: ttyPS0 at MMIO 0xe0001000 (irq = 82, base_baud = 3125000) is a xuartps
[   13.207734] console [ttyPS0] enabled
[   13.207734] console [ttyPS0] enabled
[   13.207735] bootconsole [earlycon0] disabled
[   13.207735] bootconsole [earlycon0] disabled
[   13.207737] xdevcfg f8007000.ps7-dev-cfg: ioremap 0xf8007000 to e0866000
[   13.207743] brd: module loaded
[   13.207746] loop: module loaded
[   13.207748] zynq-qspi e000d000.ps7-qspi: master is unqueued, this is deprecated
[   13.207749] zynq-qspi e000d000.ps7-qspi: at 0xE000D000 mapped to 0xE0868000, irq=51
[   13.207752] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.3.2-k
[   13.207753] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2013 Intel Corporation.
[   13.207754] libphy: XEMACPS mii bus: probed
[   13.207755] xemacps e000b000.ps7-ethernet: pdev->id -1, baseaddr 0xe000b000, irq 54
[   13.207757] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[   13.207758] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[   13.207759] ULPI transceiver vendor/product ID 0x0424/0x0007
[   13.207760] Found SMSC USB3320 ULPI transceiver.
[   13.207761] ULPI integrity check: passed.
[   13.207761] zynq-ehci zynq-ehci.0: Xilinx Zynq USB EHCI Host Controller
[   13.207763] zynq-ehci zynq-ehci.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[   13.207769] zynq-ehci zynq-ehci.0: irq 53, io mem 0x00000000
[   13.207772] zynq-ehci zynq-ehci.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[   13.207773] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[   13.207774] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   13.207775] usb usb1: Product: Xilinx Zynq USB EHCI Host Controller
[   13.207776] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-xilinx ehci_hcd
[   13.207777] usb usb1: SerialNumber: zynq-ehci.0
[   13.207779] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   13.207779] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[   13.207781] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   13.207782] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[   13.207783] i2c /dev entries driver
[   13.207784] cdns-i2c e0004000.ps7-i2c: 400 kHz mmio e0004000 irq 57
[   13.207787] xadcps f8007100.ps7-xadc: enabled:       yes     reference:      external
[   13.207788] cdns-wdt f8005000.ps7-wdt: Xilinx Watchdog Timer at e0876000 with timeout 10s
[   13.207790] zynq-edac f8006000.ps7-ddrc: ecc not enabled
[   13.207791] Xilinx Zynq CpuIdle Driver started
[   13.207590] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[   13.207591] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[   13.207592] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[   13.207593] sdhci-arasan e0100000.ps7-sdio: dummy supplies not allowed
[   13.207594] mmc0: no vqmmc regulator found
[   13.207595] sdhci-arasan e0100000.ps7-sdio: dummy supplies not allowed
[   13.207596] mmc0: no vmmc regulator found
[   13.207603] mmc0: SDHCI controller on e0100000.ps7-sdio [e0100000.ps7-sdio] using ADMA
[   13.207608] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   13.207608] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   13.207609] TCP: cubic registered
[   13.207610] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[   13.207611] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[   13.207612] drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[   13.207614] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 59b4
[   13.207615] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 USD   14.7 GiB 
[   13.207617]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[   13.207618] RAMDISK: gzip image found at block 0
[   13.207691] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using zynq-ehci
[   13.207707] VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) on device 1:0.
Starting rcS...
```

@sawdust: I don't have a `/init` file. I think `/linuxrc` is the first thing that is executed, and that is just a symlink to busybox.

Comment: First thing to do is look at what is in the file **/init** on your target.

Comment: I think you need to put more information like kernel command line parameters, bootlog of you embedded Linux system so that it can be analyzed.

Comment: *"Here are the bootlogs up to the moment that the init script is started"* -- You left out the salient part!  The HW initialization (that you posted) is not interesting for this issue.   How did you build the rootfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem. Apparently, adding `root=/dev/ram` to the boot parameters does the trick. I saw that being recommended somewhere online, but I can't find the link anymore. I'm not entirely sure why this is necessary, but it works :-)

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this through google: The reason this works is that you are not using an initrd anymore, but a normal init. Here a `tmpfs` is mounted as rootfs and init is run from there. Also, you should pass the `init=/linuxrc` parameter to the kernel, or otherwise move the init to a default place (like `/sbin/init`) to make this actually work.